# Evaluating a function at a point where $x =$ matrix.

Tags: calculus, matrices, functions

Given $A=\left(
\begin{array} {lcr}
1 & -1\\
2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)$
and $f(x)=x^2-3x+3$ calculate $f(A)$.
I tried to consider the constant $3$ as $3$ times the identity matrix ($3I$) but the answer is wrong. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Simply calculate $\;A^2-3A+3I\;$ ....

Comment: You are right, $f(A)=A^2-3A+3I_2$. Please show your computation in detail.

Comment: @Timbuc ,I try this method but the answer is just wrong. . .the answer is \begin{array} {lcr}
 -1 & -1\\
 2 & 1
 \end{array}
 \right)$

Comment: @user229922 Are you sure this is the function? Computing the charachteristic polynomial I get $\chi_A(x)= x^2 -4 x +3$. So, from Cayley's Hamilton theorem you know that $\chi_A(A)=0$.

If this is not the case, then you have to evaluate the powers of the matric which is not that difficult here since the matrix is $2\times 2$.

Comment: If the answer is wrong then either you did some mistake of the given answer is wrong.

Comment: Thank you guys. I did make a stupid mistake. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

We find that
$$
A^2 = \pmatrix{
-1 & -4\\
8 & 7}, \quad 
-3A = 
\pmatrix{
-3&3\\
-6&-9}, \quad
3I = \pmatrix{
3&0\\0&3
}
$$
Adding these together, we find
$$
f(A) = \pmatrix{
-1&-1\\
2&1
}
$$

Comment: I find my mistake...Thank you. I consider the identity matrix as all 1 there.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(A) = A^2 - 3A + 3I$$

But you know that $$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -4 \\ 8 & 7  
\end{pmatrix}$$

So, $$f(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -4 \\ 8 & 7  
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 3 \\ -6 & -9  
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3  
\end{pmatrix}$$

Simplifying leads to $$\bbox[10px, border: 2px solid lightblue]{f(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\ 2 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ 2 & 3  
\end{pmatrix}^2 - 3\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 3   \end{pmatrix} + 3\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix} $

$f(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -4 \\ 8 & 7  
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 3 \\ -6 & -9  
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3  
\end{pmatrix}$

$f(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\ 2 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}$